# Read Hash data from Yaml string

Tags: html, perl, hash, yaml

How to read hash Data from Yaml using Perl

```
my $config = $Self->{YAMLObject}->Load( Data => $Data[7] );
```

The yaml data [$Data[7] has this] :

---

DefaultValue: ''

Link: ''

PossibleNone: 1

PossibleValues:

A: A

B: B

C: C

TranslatableValues: 0

---

i want to extract "PossibleValues" and show as a dropdown field in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

Well.  Try starting with the [YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML) module.

```
$ cat foo
DefaultValue: ''
Link: ''
PossibleNone: 1
PossibleValues:
 A: A
 B: B
 C: C
TranslatableValues: 0

$ perl -MYAML=LoadFile -le 'print for keys LoadFile("foo")->{PossibleValues}'
A
C
B
```